# Rails 4 Openshift App Won't Migrate Database Tables Upon Git Push

Tags: openshift

I deployed a Rails 4 from my Github account. The application built perfectly, and I was extremely pleased by the performance.

I wanted to extend the functionally of the application, and I cloned the the app with git, added a few database tables with rails scaffold, migrated the database, and pushed the result back to OpenShift. While the original functionality continues to work, the pages that depend on the new tables have error pages that say "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Other cosmetic changes to the original pages have worked fine after pushing them to the to the OpenShift repository. This leads me to believe that OpenShift is not correctly migrating in the database tables, despite wiping out my data after each push.

I've read elsewhere that I may need to to add an action-hook to a .openshift folder, but no such folder exists in the OpenShift repo.  (I've checked for hidden folders.)  Strangely, the problem persists when I delete the entire app and recreate it from scratch - elements from before the first deploy work fine, latter additions do not.

I'm happy to provide any log file data upon request.  This is my first live rails app, and I simply do not know what to look for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the official Rails4 example on github (https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example), you should copy the .openshift directory from this git repo (https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example/tree/master/.openshift) into your application, do a git add, and a git push, and that should solve your issues.